# VTK object coloring by Data Array support in XTK?

Tags: xtk

Does XTK support object coloring by data array parsed from VTK file? I Believe the parser does read these arrays but i haven't found a way to apply those to an object.

Will or could this be supported in future versions of XTK?

- Kimmo

Answer (score 0):

You are right - the feature is not there yet and targeted for release 4 (4/12/12). We would welcome any contributions regarding this important feature :)

The infrastructure on the X.object side is already there: X.object.colors which associates a color to each vertex.

Cheers!